# How to create 3 cards with the same height with Bootstrap and flexbox?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I need to align 3 blocks in height and fix the yellow block at the bottom of its parent.

here is my result :

[image]

The yellow block is not in the frame because of the height of the grey block.

I know that my "h-100" Boostrap class is the problem but I can't find any other solution

Do you have a solution?

Thanks

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-1 mb-md-2">
    <a class="my-card d-block h-100" href="#">
      <div class="alert-container additional-message mb-0">
        <p class="alert"><span class="alert-title">txt</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="p-1 px-lg-2 h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
        <!-- RED BLOCK -->
        <div class="bg-danger">
          <p class="mb-0 lead font-weight-bold">title</p>
          <p class="mb-0 -mt-1 mt-md-0 ">3h</p>
        </div>
        <!-- YELLOW BLOCK -->
        <div class="bg-warning">
          <p class="mt-lg-1 mb-0 text-gray3"> txt <span class="d-none d-md-inline"> - </span><br class="d-block d-md-none"> tx t </p>
          <span class="btn btn-secondary mt-1 mt-lg-2">button</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-1 mb-md-2">
    <a class="my-card d-block h-100" href="#">
      <div class="alert-container additional-message mb-0">
        <p class="alert"><span class="alert-title">txt</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="p-1 px-lg-2 h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
        <!-- RED BLOCK -->
        <div class="bg-danger">
          <p class="mb-0 lead font-weight-bold">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
            survived not only five centuries, but also</p>
          <p class="mb-0 -mt-1 mt-md-0 ">3h</p>
        </div>
        <!-- YELLOW BLOCK -->
        <div class="bg-warning">
          <p class="mt-lg-1 mb-0 text-gray3"> txt <span class="d-none d-md-inline"> - </span><br class="d-block d-md-none"> tx t </p>
          <span class="btn btn-secondary mt-1 mt-lg-2">button</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-1 mb-md-2">
    <a class="my-card d-block h-100" href="#">
      <div class="alert-container additional-message mb-0">
        <p class="alert"><span class="alert-title">txt</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="p-1 px-lg-2 h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
        <!-- RED BLOCK -->
        <div class="bg-danger">
          <p class="mb-0 lead font-weight-bold">title</p>
          <p class="mb-0 -mt-1 mt-md-0 ">3h</p>
        </div>
        <!-- YELLOW BLOCK -->
        <div class="bg-warning">
          <p class="mt-lg-1 mb-0 text-gray3"> txt <span class="d-none d-md-inline"> - </span><br class="d-block d-md-none"> tx t </p>
          <span class="btn btn-secondary mt-1 mt-lg-2">button</span></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add flex column layout to the anchor elements also, and add `flex-fill` to the red boxes.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 mb-1 mb-md-2">
      <a class="my-card d-block h-100" href="#">
        <div class="alert-container additional-message mb-0">
          <p class="alert"><span class="alert-title">txt</span></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="p-1 px-lg-2 h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
          <!-- RED BLOCK -->
          <div class="bg-danger flex-fill">
            <p class="mb-0 lead font-weight-bold">title</p>
            <p class="mb-0 -mt-1 mt-md-0 ">3h</p>
          </div>
          
          <!-- YELLOW BLOCK -->
          <div class="bg-warning">
            <p class="mt-lg-1 mb-0 text-gray3"> txt <span class="d-none d-md-inline"> - </span><br class="d-block d-md-none"> tx t </p>
            <span class="btn btn-secondary mt-1 mt-lg-2">button</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4 mb-1 mb-md-2">
      <a class="my-card d-block flex-column h-100" href="#">
        <div class="alert-container additional-message mb-0">
          <p class="alert"><span class="alert-title">txt</span></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="p-1 px-lg-2 h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
          <!-- RED BLOCK -->
          <div class="bg-danger flex-fill">
            <p class="mb-0 lead font-weight-bold">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p class="mb-0 -mt-1 mt-md-0 ">3h</p>
          </div>
          
          <!-- YELLOW BLOCK -->
          <div class="bg-warning">
            <p class="mt-lg-1 mb-0 text-gray3"> txt <span class="d-none d-md-inline"> - </span><br class="d-block d-md-none"> tx t </p>
            <span class="btn btn-secondary mt-1 mt-lg-2">button</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4 mb-1 mb-md-2">
      <a class="my-card d-block h-100" href="#">
        <div class="alert-container additional-message mb-0">
          <p class="alert"><span class="alert-title">txt</span></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="p-1 px-lg-2 h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
          <!-- RED BLOCK -->
          <div class="bg-danger flex-fill">
            <p class="mb-0 lead font-weight-bold">title</p>
            <p class="mb-0 -mt-1 mt-md-0 ">3h</p>
          </div>
          
          <!-- YELLOW BLOCK -->
          <div class="bg-warning">
            <p class="mt-lg-1 mb-0 text-gray3"> txt <span class="d-none d-md-inline"> - </span><br class="d-block d-md-none"> tx t </p>
            <span class="btn btn-secondary mt-1 mt-lg-2">button</span></div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments. Post a new question with your information.